# Replace a single occurrence of an element in a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am given a list, an element to be replaced and the replacement for that element. I managed to do it for all occurrences of the element in that list:

```
replace([],X,Y,[]).
replace([X|T], X, Y, Z) :-
   replace(T, X, Y, Z1),
   Z = [Y|Z1].
replace([H|T], X, Y, [H|Z]) :-
   replace(T, X, Y, Z).
```

However now I must only replace the first occurrence of that element.
My thought process writing:

```
replace([X|T], X, Y, Z) :-
   replace(T, X, Y, Z1), 
   Z = [Y|Z1].
```

was:
 `Z` is the result of `[X|T],X,Y` if `Z1` is the result of `T`,`XY` and `Z = [Y|Z1]`. Following the same thought process I tried writing the function that only replaces the first occurrence of the element like so:

An idea for implementing only the first occurrence would be from a `replace/4` to go in a `replace/5` where I count if I replaced or not like so:

```
replace_single(L,X,Y,Z) :- 
   replace2(L,X,Y,0,Z).

replace2([],X,Y,C,[]).
replace2([X|T], X, Y, C, Z) :-
   \+ (C = 0),
   replace2(T, X, Y, C, Z1),
   Z = [X|Z1],
   C is 1.
replace2([H|T], X, Y, C, [H|Z]) :-
   replace2(T, X, Y, C, Z).
```

Obviously it will not work, I am a little bit lost. Could someone give me a tip or so of how I could think to solve the problem or the solution itself?

Comment: just stop the recursion `replace([X|T], X, T, T)`. But I would drop the last argument altogether

Comment: replace_single([],X,Y,[]).
 
 replace_single([X|T], X, Y, [Y|T]).
 replace_single([H|T], X, Y, [H|Z]) :- replace_single(T, X, Y, Z). oh like this. I am so bad :)) hhaha. You can post the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define `replace/4` based upon `same_length/2`, [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append), [`maplist/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist), and [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif):

```
replace(Xs,X,Y,Ys) :-
   same_length(Xs,Ys),
   append(Prefix,[X|Suffix],Xs),
   maplist(dif(X),Prefix),
   append(Prefix,[Y|Suffix],Ys).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- replace(Xs,2,two,[1,two,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2]).
  Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2]
; false.

?- replace([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2],2,two,Ys).
  Ys = [1,two,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2]
; false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use a DCG:

```
rep1(X, Y, [Z|T]) --> [Z], { dif(Z, X) }, rep1(X, Y, T).
rep1(X, Y, [Y|T]) --> [X], rest(T).
rep1(_, _, []) --> [].

rest([]) --> [].
rest([H|T]) --> [H], rest(T).

| ?- phrase(rep1(a, 1, L), [a,b,c,a,d]).

L = [1,b,c,a,d] ? ;

| ?- phrase(rep1(a, 1, [x, y, 1, b]), L).

L = [x,y,1,b] ? a

L = [x,y,a,b]
```

You can write your predicate as:

```
replace(X, Y, L, R) :- phrase(rep1(X, Y, R), L).
```

Comment: Using [tag:dcg] is good! Bur, AFAICT the OP quite explicitly stated that only the first occurrence of the given item is to be replaced. Don't you concur?

Comment: @repeat I updated the solution to align with the OP's requirement. Although it does leave a pesky choice point.

Comment: [tag:dcg], or no [tag:dcg], that is the question: either way, `if_/3` and `if_//3` are beckoning!

Comment: What about the "nop"-solution of `phrase(rep1(a, 1, [x, y, 1, b]), L)`? My interpretation would have been: "if we know that `[x,y,1,b]` is the result of rep1 having been applied once, then that first occurence of must be turned into `a` again... What's your stance?

Comment: Promise: I will start a bounty on this question ASAP. (Right now it is too young.)

Comment: @repeat We do not know for sure that `[x, y, 1, b]` is the result of replacing anything by `1`. We only know that it is one of the possibilities, with no higher or lower probability than the original list just being `[x, y, 1, b]`. Unless, of course, we arbitrarily wish to define it otherwise. :) BTW my answer was downvoted by someone. With my correction, I do not think it deserves a downvote even with the dangling choice point.

Comment: @repeat, on the other DCG of a few weeks ago, I tried `if_/3` and `if_//3` in various ways and couldn't get rid of the choice point. I might go back to it at some time, however. I probably was staring at it too long.

Comment: I know that feeling;)  Why not do it in a ping-pong SO-style? Stop whenever you're stuck---refrain from digging deeper when you're in a hole. Instead, write a comment, make a MVCE, pass the ball. Let's do it!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it will be:-

```
replace(E1,L1,E2,L2) :-
same_length(L1,L2),
append(BeforeElement,[E1|AfterElement],L1),
append(BeforeElement,[E2|AfterElement],L2).
```

where BeforeElement stands for prefix of the list before the element and After Element stands for suffix of the list after the element.